# Python how to count groups of duplicates?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and the problem I'm facing is how can I count groups of duplicates. For example given a list like this:

`['down', 'down', 'down', 'up', 'right', 'right', 'down', 'down']`

I have to calculate the following:

`[('down', 3), ('up', 1), ('right', 2), ('down', 2)]`

Or rather how can I achieve this in a pythonic way coming from languages like java/c#?

EDIT: Since it seems that I didn't clarify my my problem enough, I don't want to count all the occurrences of for example `down` in the list, but only those that are neighbors (if that is the correct phrasing), so `Counter(my_list)` doesn't give the desired output.

Comment: What is the data structure you expect to get? because what you asked is not a valid one.

Comment: It should have been {'down' : 3, 'up' : 1, 'right' : 2, 'down' : 2} right? Like a Hashmap in java

Comment: Still not valid, you can't have 'down' twice in a dict

Comment: @MaorRefaeli sorry, I hope that it's good now with using a tuple.

Comment: List of tuples is a better data structure for your implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = ['down', 'down', 'down', 'up', 'right', 'right', 'down', 'down']
>>> [(value, sum(1 for _ in group)) for value, group in itertools.groupby(lst)]
[('down', 3), ('up', 1), ('right', 2), ('down', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
from itertools import groupby
[(c,len(list(cgen))) for c,cgen in groupby(a)]
```

Comment: could you please elaborate as to have that solution works?

Comment: `groupby` gives group of same element like:
`[('down', <itertools._grouper at 0x7f4438b1b320>),
 ('up', <itertools._grouper at 0x7f4438b1b6d8>),
 ('right', <itertools._grouper at 0x7f4438b1b5f8>),
 ('down', <itertools._grouper at 0x7f4438b1b278>)]
`
So for each print the element and length of group.